# sed not working in for loop in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sed

I'm trying to replace all strings in 'toReplace.txt' matched with strings specified in 'replaceList.txt' one by one with an integer index using a for loop in bash shell script:

```
source='toReplace.txt'
map='replaceList.txt'
label=`cat $map`
index=1
for item in $label
do
  sed -i "s/$item/$index/g" $source
  index=$(( index + 1 ))
done
```

However the sed command works well out of the loop or in the command line console but once I put it in the for loop it doesn't work any more. If I run the above code, nothing actually changes with toReplace.txt.

Anyone has any idea what is wrong here? Many thanks!

Thanks all for the insight! An example of the .txt files

```
#toReplace.txt
3.66519 0
5.75959 0
1.39626 1.0472
5.23599 0.174533
1.91986 0.698132
1.0472 1.0472
2.61799 0.698132

#replaceList
0.174533
0.349066
0.523599
0.698132
0.872665
1.0472
1.22173
1.39626
1.5708
1.74533
1.91986
2.09439
2.26893
2.44346
2.61799
```

Basically I want to replace all float type numbers in toReplace.txt with the index (the # of line) of this float type number in replaceList.txt.

[Output for @narendra's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmVhd.png)

The output for @narendra's code is as above. Still nothing changed in my toReplace.txt. Anyone's got any idea what the issue is??

Comment: Can you provide examples of what is in the files please?

Comment: You are trying to replace strings from `replaceList.txt` in the `toReplace.txt` file with a number?

Comment: try using while loop instead of cat to file in variable and then looping using FOR... while read line; do ...your code here... done < $map

Comment: I tested your code for simple examples and it works as expected. Can there be spaces in the pattern?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, exactly!

Comment: @t_thirupathi Thank you! Could you try again with the sample provided? In my case nothing actually changed in `toReplace.txt`. If I echo $index and $item, they all iterate as expected.

Comment: @123 Please check updated question ;)

Comment: @narendra, yes, your code works for the sample input you've provided. This is the output I got (in toReplace.text). 
3.66519 0
5.75959 0
8 6
5.23599 1
11 4
6 6
15 4. 

Do you expect something else?

Comment: @t_thirupathi Thanks for help to test! I'm not expecting anything else - that's exactly what I want. But on my machine nothing changed in toReplace.txt. All I got is just float point numbers. Weird...

Answer (score 0):

try as below ...

```
source='toReplace.txt'
map='replaceList.txt'
index=1
while read item
do
  # comment below echo once done testing
  echo "replacing $item with $index ..."
  sed -i "s/${item}/${index}/g" $source
  index=$(( index + 1 ))
done < $map
```

Comment: Could you explain what difference it makes?

Comment: 1. Its not recommented to use for loop to read file line by line ... read link http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 2. if line contains any space it will be treated as single line instead of breaking it into multiple items

Comment: Thanks narendra, I tried your code but nothing changed in toReplace.txt. The output is like: `with 1 ....174533
 with 2 ....349066
 with 3 ....523599
 with 4 ....698132
 with 5 ....872665
 with 6 ....0472
 with 7 ....22173
 with 8 ....39626
 with 9 ....5708
 with 10 ...74533
 with 11 ...91986
 with 12 ...09439
 with 13 ...26893
 with 14 ...44346
 with 15 ...61799`

Comment: I only see decimal part in the output..looks like some issue with variable interpretation...can you put the variables in curly braces...and try again I updated my answer above...

Comment: I tried your updated code and I've uploaded the screenshot for the output. Still nothing changed in my toReplace.txt...